# Django 1.9 sr_Latn locale doesn't work

Tags: django, localization, internationalization, locale

In Django 1.6.5 the following worked:
in settings.py

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('sr_Latn', 'Srpski'),
    ('en', 'English'),
)
```

whereas the locale folder with translation was also called ***sr_Latn***.

With Django 1.9.2. sr_Latn is not recognized as a language code any more so I have to enter sr-latn, but then the locale folder is not found - regardless if it is called sr-latn, sr-Latn, sr_latn or sr_Latn.

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('sr-latn', 'Srpski'),
    ('en', 'English'),
)
```

This problem is specific to Serbian-Latin only because that is the only locale to have such a funny format.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out Django devs did it right this time. The following setup worked like a charm:

Settings:

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('sr-latn', 'Srpski'),
    ('en-gb', 'English'),
)

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    # translation files on the server must be in the same folder as this
    # settings file and this path must point to the translations.
    # Dev server works anyway with this path. 
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "locale"),
)
```

I have locale folder in the Project folder:

```
./project-folder/
    locale/
        sr_Latn/
            LC_MESSAGES/
                django.mo
                django.po
        en_GB/
            LC_MESSAGES/
                django.mo
                django.po
```

Everything finaly makes sense.